# I am looking for a pdf version of Skanda Purana, in Sanskrit "and" its translation (either English or Hindi) in the same book

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, krishna

I am looking for a pdf version of Skanda Purana, in Sanskrit "and" its translation (either English or Hindi) in the same book. Its quite important! Please let me know!